# unable to pass a link variable inside append in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a fetch the JSON records from the database I need to link a href tag to the code but unable. Whats wrong with me? In a console, I see simple `td` without a `href` tag.

```js
htmlData += '<tr><td><a href="base_url + "'order/getWork/'" + ord_id">'
+ord_item_Json_string[i].code+'</a></td>
<td>'+ord_item_Json_string[i].item+'</td>
<td>'+ord_item_Json_string[i].size+'</td>
<td>'+ord_item_Json_string[i].color+'</td>
<td>'+ord_item_Json_string[i].qty+'</td><td>'+"New Order"+'</td>
<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="create-jobcard">Create Card</button></td>
</tr>';

$('#OrdItem tbody').empty();
$('#OrdItem tbody').append(htmlData);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a problem with quotations marks( "" / '' ) try this out,

```
htmlData += '<tr><td><a href="'+base_url+'order/getWork/" + ord_id">' 
+ord_item_Json_string[i].code+'</a></td>
<td>'+ord_item_Json_string[i].item+'</td>
<td>'+ord_item_Json_string[i].size+'</td>
<td>'+ord_item_Json_string[i].color+'</td>
<td>'+ord_item_Json_string[i].qty+'</td><td>'+"New Order"+'</td>
<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="create-jobcard">Create Card</button></td>
</tr>';
```

hope this helps